# Search Query Sample Size Determination for validation set

Tags: statistics, sampling, search, search-engine, learning-to-rank

While designing a search system, which searches in N identifiable categories, how many search queries does one need in each category to validate the target metric (DCG) scores accurately (balanced variance and bias)? does this number depend on N or the corpus size or both? Please add any publications possible.
I would also like the understand if effect size and and bayesian effective sample sizes play some role here. 
Given a set of search queries **Q** for retrieving documents from another set ***D***, where there are **N** possible categories in the corpus with **k(n)** documents in each set, the objective is to define test minset(**Q**) such that DCG obtained is reliable.

Example: Searching for Fruits 
Search queries: [Red apple, Green apple] 
Category: Apple
Documents: [Red Apple, Gala Apple, Green Apple,...]k1 documents
Search queries: [Alphonso, Haden, Keitt]
Category: Mango
Documents: [Keitt, Kent, Haden,....]k2 documents
.
.
.
The search results will be ranked and the accuracy of search is measured with DCG. How many search queries do you need in each set to have a reliable DCG as a function of the categories and the document set?

Comment: Could you please declare your input/ output variables more formally?